# how to dispose() current JIntenalFrame in java

Tags: java, swing, windowlistener

> how to `dispose()` current `JIntenalFrame` ?

```
public class A extends JIntenalFrame
{
 class B extends JIntenalFrame
  {
   //i like to dispose current B class to dispose()
   B.dispose();
   }
}
```

i am working with some inner `JIntenalFrame`.
is there is any way to dispose it?

Comment: `this.dispose()`? - If you take the time to look at the [JavaDocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JInternalFrame.html) you'll find it's an instance method. If you want to know which frame is the "current" frame, then  you'll need to look at [`JDesktopPane`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JDesktopPane.html)

Comment: i used `this.dispose()` then it close the parent.class.

Comment: Then you have a problem which is not been highlighted from the out of context you've posted. Consider providing a [runnable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which demonstrates your problem. This is not a code dump, but an example of what you are doing which highlights the problem you are having. This will result in less confusion and better responses

Comment: thank you for your value able comments. means alot :) and the answer given bellow @MadProgrammer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> all inner class are working on the there own path so a follows the path we can use it

```
 public class Main extends JIntenalFrame
{
 public class A extends JIntenalFrame
  {
   //its an inner class
  }
 public class B extends JIntenalFrame
  {
   /*now while disposing the class B extended by the JIntenalFrame
then use the class name and the operation()
*/
 B.this.dispose();//here the actual working code
  }
}
```

if you use inside the `this.dispose()` then it will close the `Main JIntenalFrame` so while working inside the `JIntenalFrame` for those operation we can use the `CLASS_NAME.this.operation()`.
like wise

`B.this.dispose();`

Answer (score 0):

You can use JDesktopPane.getSelectedFrame().dispose();

Comment: you are right almost but while i am using it will close the parent if i used`JDekstop.dispose()` and if i used your given  `JDesktopPane.getSelectedFrame().dispose();` so it will only working in my project from outside of the `JIntenalFrame` but thanks to you,you given me the idea for class and there path while working with inner class content thank you so so much...god bless u..